# How to use CloudFormation to delete Evidently Launch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, evidently

Is it possible to delete an AWS Evidently Launch using CloudFormation?

Usually removing a resource from the stack causes the resource to be deleted, but that is not happening with launches.

CloudFormation AWS::Evidently::Launch - create or update documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-evidently-launch.html

AWS SDK to delete Launch (which I don't want to use, all of our infrastructure is scripted.):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatchevidently/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteLaunch.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

In our case, it was failing to delete the launch due to missing permissions for stopping the launch, which is required before deleting. Even though deleting failed, the stack showed as completing successfully so we didn't notice what had happened immediately.